# What module / service should I use to push message from Node.js server to Mobile App written in Unity?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

Here is my set up:

Node.js server with RedisCloud, and client mobile app written in Unity C#.

I'm trying to push message from Node.js server to UnityC#.

At first, I try to get Unity access RedisDB directly but that is too dangerous having Client connecting to DB, and open the port.

So, what module works well between Node.js & Unity for message pub/sub?  or 3rd party services that takes data from Redis, and push to Client?

I think socket.io will work but it seems just too much work for Client to write code handling that.

Is there something like Firebase or Photon, but instead using Firebase DB, point to my own RedisDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile client is for iOS then you should use "Apple Push Notifications", if Android, you should use "Google Cloud Messaging".

You can easily find modules for these tasks on npm, for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcm

Comment: this is in-game message / data push to client. so i don't think I can use APple Push Notification. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a Cloud service like Pusher or Realtime (the company I work for). Simply subscribe a channel on your mobile app using the Realtime Unity SDK and publish the messages from your server using the Node.js SDK. You don't need to worry about the dirty backend details (security, scalability,...)

More at http://framework.realtime.co/messaging

Comment: I'm looking at realtime too, also compare to Photon.  How do send message to realtime server for specific user?  by unique channel id?

Comment: Make each user user subscribe a private channel, maybe using the userid. Then publish to that channel.